# Replace Elements of a Div with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a contact form in a wordpress site that displays a message to user when they fail to fill in form items. It is in english and I want to replace it with text in spanish. I have no idea where the files to replace this text would be so using Jquery seems the easiest thing to use.
Here is the warning message:

```
    <div class="et-pb-contact-message">
      <p>Please, fill in the following fields:</p>
      <ul>
       <li>Nombre</li>
       <li>Email Address</li>
       <li>Mensaje</li>
       <li>Captcha</li>
      </ul>
```

This is what I am trying but somehow it is not working:

```
    <script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {  
    var div_data  =  "<p>Favor de llenar correctamente los campos:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Nombre</li>
      <li>Email </li>
      <li>Mensaje</li>
      <li>Seguridad</li>
    </ul>";
     $(".et-pb-contact-message").html(div_data);
   });
   </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does you site remaining content in spanish language?

Comment: @GokulShinde No it is not. Here is the link: http://www.elementgym.com.mx/contacto/   (Well... the content is in spanish)

Comment: Then why only success message you want in spanish? Actually you can do it with php.

Comment: The users are spanish speaking and client wants that message in spanish.

Answer (score 2):

The newlines in `div_data` messed up your string. You can replace the double quotes with a backtick (the key before the 1 key on the keyboard) like so. This is a new feature in ECMAScript 6 (ES6) called a template literal.

```
var div_data  =  `<p>Favor de llenar correctamente los campos:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Nombre</li>
      <li>Email </li>
      <li>Mensaje</li>
      <li>Seguridad</li>
    </ul>`;
```

Or more commonly concat strings per line

```
var div_data  =  "<p>Favor de llenar correctamente los campos:</p>"+
    "<ul>"+
      "<li>Nombre</li>"+
      "<li>Email </li>"+
      "<li>Mensaje</li>"+
      "<li>Seguridad</li>"+
   "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, a line break marks the end of a statement, so your multi-line string is causing the error when it moves to the next line and sees `<`, which is an unexpected character to the parser. Try putting the string all on one line, and that should correct the error.

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {  
    var div_data  =  "<p>Favor de llenar correctamente los campos:</p><ul><li>Nombre</li><li>Email </li><li>Mensaje</li><li>Seguridad</li></ul>";
     $(".et-pb-contact-message").html(div_data);
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively, in ECMAScript 6, the backtick character (`) can be used to denote a multi-line string, or a 'Template Literal' as they refer to it in the documentation.

Comment: Both of the answers (@Eric Guan and @ShamSUP ) handled the original problem but now this generated another one which is that the message display regardless of user errors in filling up the form. ???

Comment: @Agustin This code will replace any html code that is in the element. So if you are putting errors inside of `.et-pb-contact-message`, then it will be replaced by this function.